# Updating DAEMON service in Mac OS X

Tags: java, service, daemon, auto-update, server

I am running my server application as a service on a mac computer using launchd. I am looking for a solution to update the server so the users won't notice the server is stopped. The server provides RESTful services to users who are expecting zero down time. The server application is written in Java.

Comment: Probably using two servers and using a load balancer? When one goes down, your services will be still running. Not sure, just speaking of my mind

Comment: Two-server solution is a bit pricy but there is no other way around it I guess. Just wondering, can you recommend any load balancer? I'm new in this topic.

Comment: http://camel.apache.org/load-balancer.html